# Collision of static variables for two applications in the same jvm

Tags: java, static, applet, jvm, singleton

I have an applet application which uses several static objects (and we can not get rid of them). The application is launched from html page. Browser creates single jvm for any amount of tabs and thus if you open two tabs with this application, the static variables will be shared with both of them. Both won't work correctly after this. We've tried to use [separate_jvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html#SEPARATE_JVM) but it doesn't work in every browser.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Barring some way to make 'separte_jvm' work, something like a a custom classloader is probably the only solution that will work.  Generally the same static field can have different values if the parent classes belong to different classloaders.  Though I've never tried using a custom classloader in an applet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This test case demonstrates how a static field in a single class can have different values, in the same JVM, when loading the class from two *instances* of a classloader:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    MyLoader customLoader1 = new MyLoader();
    MyLoader customLoader2 = new MyLoader();

    Class<?> c1 = customLoader1.loadClass(SPECIAL_CLASS_NAME);
    Class<?> c2 = customLoader2.loadClass(SPECIAL_CLASS_NAME);

    LoadedClass o1 = (LoadedClass) c1.newInstance();
    LoadedClass o2 = (LoadedClass) c2.newInstance();

    o1.setStaticPart(100d);
    o2.setStaticPart(1d);

    assertEquals(100d, o1.getStaticPart());
    assertEquals(1d, o2.getStaticPart());
}
```

How to use a custom classloader in an applet I leave as an exercise for the reader.  :-)